# How to get the all the pricing value from the json array

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

How to get all the pricing values from the JSON array? I need to split two segments tld's (com,in,in.net,etc...) and the corresponding tld pricing value I tried to get the values from the array but com, in etc those are key values.

My JSON Array

```
Array
(
[result] => success
[pricing] => Array
    (
        [com] => Array
            (
                [categories] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => gTLD
                        [1] => Popular
                    )

                [addons] => Array
                    (
                        [dns] => 1
                        [email] => 1
                        [idprotect] => 1
                    )

                [group] => sale
                [register] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 637.70
                    )

                [transfer] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 637.70
                    )

                [renew] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 637.70
                    )

               )

        [in] => Array
            (
                [categories] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => ccTLD
                        [1] => Geography
                    )

                [addons] => Array
                    (
                        [dns] => 1
                        [email] => 1
                        [idprotect] => 1
                    )

                [group] => sale
                [register] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 1014.67
                    )

                [transfer] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 1014.67
                    )

                [renew] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 1014.67
                    )

            )

        [info] => Array
            (
                [categories] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => gTLD
                        [1] => Popular
                    )

                [addons] => Array
                    (
                        [dns] => 1
                        [email] => 1
                        [idprotect] => 1
                    )

                [group] => sale
                [register] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 200.00
                    )

                [transfer] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 200.00
                    )

                [renew] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 200.00
                    )

            )

        [net] => Array
            (
                [categories] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => gTLD
                        [1] => Popular
                    )

                [addons] => Array
                    (
                        [dns] => 1
                        [email] => 1
                        [idprotect] => 1
                    )

                [group] => sale
                [register] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 829.76
                    )

                [transfer] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 829.76
                    )

                [renew] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 829.76
                    )

            )

        [biz] => Array
            (
                [categories] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => gTLD
                        [1] => Popular
                    )

                [addons] => Array
                    (
                        [dns] => 1
                        [email] => 1
                        [idprotect] => 1
                    )

                [group] => sale
                [register] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 878.33
                    )

                [transfer] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 878.33
                    )

                [renew] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 878.33
                    )

            )

        [org] => Array
            (
                [categories] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => gTLD
                        [1] => Popular
                    )

                [addons] => Array
                    (
                        [dns] => 1
                        [email] => 1
                        [idprotect] => 1
                    )

                [group] => sale
                [register] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 939.45
                    )

                [transfer] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 939.45
                    )

                [renew] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 939.45
                    )

            )

        [asia] => Array
            (
                [categories] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => gTLD
                        [1] => ccTLD
                        [2] => Geography
                        [3] => Popular
                    )

                [addons] => Array
                    (
                        [dns] => 1
                        [email] => 1
                        [idprotect] => 1
                    )

                [group] => sale
                [register] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 1527.88
                    )

                [transfer] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 1527.88
                    )

                [renew] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 1527.88
                    )

            )

        [co.uk] => Array
            (
                [categories] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => ccTLD
                        [1] => Geography
                    )

                [addons] => Array
                    (
                        [dns] => 1
                        [email] => 1
                        [idprotect] => 1
                    )

                [group] => sale
                [register] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 602.53
                    )

                [transfer] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 602.53
                    )

                [renew] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 602.53
                    )

            )

        [in.net] => Array
            (
                [categories] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Other
                    )

                [addons] => Array
                    (
                        [dns] => 1
                        [email] => 1
                        [idprotect] => 1
                    )

                [group] => sale
                [register] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 100.00
                    )

                [transfer] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 100.00
                    )

                [renew] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 100.00
                    )

            )

        [uk] => Array
            (
                [categories] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => ccTLD
                        [1] => Geographic
                        [2] => Popular
                    )

                [addons] => Array
                    (
                        [dns] => 1
                        [email] => 1
                        [idprotect] => 1
                    )

                [group] => sale
                [register] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 200.00
                    )

                [transfer] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 300.00
                    )

                [renew] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 400.00
                    )

            )

    )

 )
```

How to split the array and get the transfer values from the above JSON array?

Comment: What is the expected output array ?

Comment: whc\ich ones are prices? what is your desired output? what have you tried and failed?

Answer (score 1):

**If I don't misunderstood your question** then this is what you need with simple `foreach()` loop to get **tlds** with their corresponding **prices**

```
$expected = [];
foreach($result['pricing'] as $tld=>$array){
   // this is the register value, you can change it for transfer or renew if you wish
   $expected[$tld] = $array['register'][1]; 
}
print_r($expected);
```